# How do I share a mount to the network?

Tags: networking, sharing

I have a spanned RAID array using an XFS file system, located in /mnt/raiddrives. How do I now share this onto my network? I would like to be able to see the share on both a Windows machine and a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Samba for both Windows and Linux, however the standard for Linux is NFS. Both Samba and NFS can coexist on the same host.

Comment: A bit more explanation would be useful (E.g. how to set up NFS for `/mnt/raiddrives`)

Comment: As I understood the question, the asker had no idea which software to use. Given the names, it's quite easy to find Tutorials and imho there's no point in copying them here.